# Tool check link died in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, nokogiri

I want to use ruby to check if a link died.
Can you tell me a tool in `ruby` to check link died in ruby ? 
Can i use `selenium` or `nokogiri`?
Thanks for your helping!

Comment: see this example - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Response+Data and http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTP+Response+Classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to make request with [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) and check if status code is 404.

For example:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('link_to_check')
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
if response.code == '404'
  # do something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that I use. It does a HEAD instead of GET request and will follow redirects properly. It also uses the generic `Net::HTTPSuccess` to check if a request was successful.

```
require 'net/http'

def alive?(link, limit=10)
  return false if limit <= 0

  link = "http://#{link}" unless link =~ %r{^https?://}i
  uri = URI.parse(link)

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  req = Net::HTTP::Head.new(uri.request_uri)
  res = http.request(req)

  case res
    when Net::HTTPSuccess then true
    when Net::HTTPRedirection then alive?(res['location'], limit-1)
    else false
  end
rescue SocketError
  false # unknown hostname
end
```

Comment: Do you know any book to learn this `lib` well or you use only documentation ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I just read the documentation, blog posts like [this one](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) and if in doubt I look at the source code. Pry makes it so easy with the `show-source` and `show-doc` commands.